Beamer: unwanted page number of bibliography appears on TOC slide when using apacite
In Beamer, when I insert a Table of Contents to appear at every section, the page number (not frame number) of the bibliography appears, unwanted, on the table of contents ("3" in the image).

This only happens with the apacite bibliographystyle.
I have never seen this behavior before now (Oct 2024), despite using the same structure with apacite in Beamer as recently as Sept 2024.

MWE:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apacite}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}
\begin{frame}{Test slide}
Unclear why the page number of the Bibliography appears on the TOC \cite{test2}.
\end{frame}

\renewcommand*{\refname}{} % This will define heading of bibliography to be empty, so you can...
\begin{frame}[plain,allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{../testbib}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

testbib.bib:
@article{test2,
    title={My little test},
    author={{Testville, Harold}},
    year={2024}
}





You can use the notocbib option to switch this off:
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[notocbib]{apacite}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{test2,
    title={My little test},
    author={{Testville, Harold}},
    year={2024}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}
\begin{frame}{Test slide}
Unclear why the page number of the Bibliography appears on the TOC \cite{test2}.
\end{frame}

\renewcommand*{\refname}{} % This will define heading of bibliography to be empty, so you can...
\begin{frame}[plain,allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


